# Convert Spark Row to typed Array of Doubles

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.3.1 with Hive and have a row object that is a long series of doubles to be passed to a Vecors.dense constructor, however when I convert a Row to an array via

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => r.toSeq.toArray}
```

All type information is lost and I get back an array of [Any] type. I am unable to cast this object to double using

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val array = r.toSeq.toArray 
  array.map(_.toDouble) 
} // Fails with value toDouble is not a member of any
```

as does

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
      val array = r.toSeq.toArray 
      array.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double]) 
    } // Fails with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I see that the Row object has an API that supports getting specific elements as a type, via:

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  r.getDouble(5)}
```

However event this fails with java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

The only work around I have found is the following:

```
 SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  doubleArray = Array(r.getInt(5).toDouble, r.getInt(6).toDouble) 
  Vectors.dense(doubleArray) }
```

However this is prohibitively tedious when index 5 through 1000 need to be converted to an array of doubles.

Any way around explicitly indexing the row object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at your code blocks 1 by 1

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val array = r.toSeq.toArray 
  val doubleArra = array.map(_.toDouble) 
} // Fails with value toDouble is not a member of any
```

Map returns the last statement as the type (i.e. there is a kind of implied return on any function in Scala that the last result is your return value). Your last statement is of type Unit (like Void).. because assigning a variable to a val has no return. To fix that, take out the assignment (this has the side benefit of being less code to read).

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val array = r.toSeq.toArray 
  array.map(_.toDouble) 
}
```

`_.toDouble` is not a cast..you can do it on a String or in your case an Integer, and it will change the instance of the variable type. If you call `_.toDouble` on a Int, it is more like doing `Double.parseDouble(inputInt)`.

`_.asInstanceOf[Double]` would be a cast.. which if your data is really a double, would change the type. But not sure you need to cast here, avoid casting if you can.

**Update**

So you changed the code to this

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val array = r.toSeq.toArray 
  array.map(_.toDouble) 
} // Fails with value toDouble is not a member of any
```

You are calling toDouble on a node of your SparkDataFrame. Apparently it is not something that has a toDouble method.. i.e. it is not an Int or a String or a Long.

If this works

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  doubleArray = Array(r.getInt(5).toDouble, r.getInt(6).toDouble) 
  Vectors.dense(doubleArray) }
```

But you need to do from 5 to 1000.. why not do

```
SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val doubleArray = for (i <- 5 to 1000){
      r.getInt(i).toDouble
  }.toArray
  Vectors.dense(doubleArray) 
 }
```

Comment: This still fails with the same errors. Fixed the code to not reflect this as an issue

Comment: @user2726995 giving someone a -1 who is trying to answer your question is not a good way to get help

Comment: I appreciate any and all  assistance, a downvote is not personal, just that the solution does not answer the direct question at hand

Comment: For posterity (for (i <- 2 to record.size) yield record.getInt(i).toDouble).toArray

Answer (score 3):

you should use the Double.parseDouble from java.

```
import  java.lang.Double

SparkDataFrame.map{r => 
  val doubleArray = for (i <- 5 to 1000){
      Double.parseDouble(r.get(i).toString)
  }.toArray
  Vectors.dense(doubleArray) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar, harder, problem in that my features are not all Double. Here's how I was able to convert from my DataFrame (pulled from Hive table as well) to a LabeledPoint RDD:

```
val loaff = oaff.map(r => 
  LabeledPoint(if (r.getString(classIdx)=="NOT_FRAUD") 0 else 1, 
  Vectors.dense(featIdxs.map(r.get(_) match {case null => Double.NaN 
                                             case d: Double => d 
                                             case l: Long => l}).toArray)))
```